# how to use data table column having special character in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below data set with header have special character and space

```
    dt=data.table("name/person list"=c("name1","name2","name3","name4"),mark=c(1,2,3,4))
```

and trying to plot this in ggplot as below

```
   ggplot(data=dt,aes(x="name/person list",y=mark)) +geom_bar(stat_count())
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Try ` instead of ".

Comment: Am getting the error as Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`

Comment: if you want the count then why having a y- aesthetic

Comment: Yes, e.g. `ggplot(dt, aes(x=`\`name/person list\``)) + geom_bar(stat = "count")` or `ggplot(dt, aes(x=`\`name/person list\``, y=mark)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Or `aes_string(x="name/person list", y="mark")`.

Comment: Thanks LukA and Roland. This works....